# Collapsible CSS left-hand column and auto-expanding right-hand column... expanding vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a tricky design to put into practice. There will be two CSS columns, the left of which is a left-hand menu (~300px) which collapses to 85px when not in use. The right column should expand to fill whatever space is available when the menu collapses.

This in itself is not too tricky and I've achieved it using the overflow: hidden trick (essentially the same as the accepted answer on [CSS layout with 2 columns, taking up all width of browser, where left column can collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560868/css-layout-with-2-columns-taking-up-all-width-of-browser-where-left-column-can))

However I am now looking at how I can have both columns expand vertically to fill the available screen space.

The variable width left-hand column seems to prevent me from using the Faux Columns technique. I'm not sure other than that.

I also have CSS transitions on the width so that the collapse/expand movement is more fluid, which I'd like to maintain.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

EDIT: This is as close as I can get: http://jsfiddle.net/tsr5a/:

```
html, body { height:100%;}
#menu { width: 100%; height: 50px; }
#container { overflow: hidden; height:100%; }
#left-column { background:yellow; float:left; height:100%; width:300px; }
#right-column { background:red; height:100%;}
#container .shrink { width:85px; }
```

I'm not sure why the right-hand column is offset vertically by 1 line. Also note that while I can set 100% height on the columns, this doesn't take into account the fixed height toolbar at the top of the page.

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle to demonstrate the issue in action?

Comment: @do_you_realise : **do you realise** that its a tricky thing and jsfiddle would be more helpful in getting an answer?? :)

Comment: Thanks :) I've added a jsfiddle of where I've managed to get so far. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Good Luck

you need include this

```
#container{display:inline-flex;width:100%; }
#right-column{;width:100%}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsr5a/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `overflow: hidden;` from your `#container` it should work as desired.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsr5a/2/)

```
#container {height:100%;}
```

***Edit:** I hope I understood your question/issue correctly.*

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't seem to solve my problem though, which is simply that I want to make each column expand to fill the screen vertically. At the moment I have `height: 100%;` on these but with the fixed height toolbar the columns are now too tall.